# Run jQuery code in a non-selected jQuery-UI tab - 1.10

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-tabs

I am trying to run jQuery code on elements contained within a jQuery tab which is not selected. If i quickly click the tab before the Ajax loading has completed it works, but if i leave it running without being selected the code will not be executed.

As ou can see below, the tab i want to load data into were not defined from the beginning, it was created when the user clicked a button.

The functionality i want to achieve is tabs, where the user will search for X in the start tab, then the new tab is created, content is loaded in the background (needs jQuery code for grids and format). Then the user can click the tab and see the results.

jQuery 1.10
jQuery-UI 1.10

Example:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

var myindex = 1;

$("#startsearch").click(function() {

    search = escape(($("#search").val()));

    searchdate = ($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date()));

    var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    var ul = tabs.find( "ul" );

    // Add new tab
    newhtml = "<li id='henrik_tab_" + myindex + "Selector'><a href='#henrik_tab_" + myindex + "'>Search: " + searchdate + "</a></li>";
    newhtml2 = "<div id='henrik_tab_" + myindex + "'></div>";
    ul.append(newhtml);
    tabs.append(newhtml2);
    tabs.tabs( "refresh" );

    // Load data into tab
    $( "#henrik_tab_" + myindex).load("dosearch.php?data=" + search, function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr) {
            if(statusTxt=="success") {

        !! DOING STUFF WITH ELEMENTS CONTAINED IN THE NEW TAB HERE !!

            }
            if(statusTxt=="error")
                    alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
    });

    // increse the counter for next tab
    myindex++;

});

$( "#tabs" ).tabs();

});
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try change code

```
tabs.append(newhtml2);
```

to

```
$( "#tabs" ).append(newhtml2);
```

If not fix, would like show the code should be executed but not.

Comment: Problem solved, i was using sparklines and that lib had a check to check for hidden elements, the elements are of course hidden when i am not in that tab.